# HX711 powered directly from coin cell

Tags: power-supply, adc, load-cell, coin-cell

Is it a good idea to use [HX711](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf) in a project (personal weight scale) that is powered directly from a coin cell (CR2032) without any external or its internal voltage regulator? I shut down the whole board when 2.6V voltage is sampled on the coin cell.
Are there any gotchas except reduced precision?

Comment: The more important value from the datasheet is: `Current consumption including on-chip analog power supply regulator: normal operation < 1.5mA, power down < 1uA`

Answer (score 0):

Coin-cell is feasible in applications that has low current draw and NO high current peaks, so the answer is yes.